# Recreating the Apple Store's summary that moves with the page scrolling

Tags: javascript, slider

I'm looking to create something like what Apple has on their online store for displaying the summary of your computer and total [as seen here](http://store.apple.com/us/configure/MC024LL/A?mco=MTc0Njg1NzI). I'm guessing this is JavaScript, but it'd be even cooler if it could be done in CSS.

Basically I'd like something scrolls with the page like `position:fixed`, but I don't want it to start moving until the user has scroll past a certain position.

I'm using jQuery, so a jQuery plugin would be perfect as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this

```
var min = 10; //Set your own here
$(window).scroll(function() { 
  var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop()
  if(scrollTop > min)
    $('.divClass').css({  top: "0" });
  else
    $('.divClass').css({ top: (min - scrollTop) + "px" });
});
```

CSS

```
.divClass
{
  position:fixed,
  left: 500px /* or whatever */
}
```

Comment: Nice. A little tweaking and it's perfect! I changed the first top:"0" to top:"10px" so there's a little padding between the div and the top of the page. I also didn't need the left:500px; in the CSS (but I do need the fixed).